# Get the first blocks of a torrent in priority

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I'd like to be able to begin to watch a video as soon as I start a torrent to download. Is there an option in transmission for enabling this functionality as in µtorrent.

Comment: See also: https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12850

Comment: Thank you. The official response: https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Can%20I%20sequence%20the%20files%20I%20download%20

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not part of Transmission, is part of the Video Player. As I know, `VLC` and `MPlayer` can play of videos "corrupted" (in this case, video with only part downloaded), but also depends of the video format as some needs the header only and other needs the entire file.

Then, as BitTorrent and `Transmission` download the files in blocks and depending of the rarity, the only thing that you can do is try with one player and ignore if the popup a window saying that the file is corrupted, and if you're lucky with the type of file, you could see it.

Sources: https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=13376&p=60672 https://superuser.com/questions/111405/how-to-preview-unfinished-torrent-video-files

Comment: The problem is not how to play incomplete video files, but to download the first parts in priority, so I do not have to wait for watching the video. But your second paragraph give the reason of the non-implementation of this functionality.

Comment: The only thing that you could do is to wait a 25% of the file (for example) and try to watch the video. That doesn't mean that you are going to watch the video perfectly because maybe the header is the first part to download but maybe the Torrent continues downloading by the end. It's not streaming.

Comment: I'm currently trying to change the weight of the pieces to give the priority to the first ones, as explained in https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Can%20I%20sequence%20the%20files%20I%20download%20